# Amazon Alexa - One intent enable utterances

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In Amazon Alexa is there a way to have one intent initialize a set of utterances?

I ask because I need to identify models of cars in addition to times and places. Adding slots for cars/places seems ridiculous as there would probably be 8000+ possibilities.

ex:

```
valetService.prototype.launch = fucntion(intent, session, response){
  if(intent.slots['vehicleType'] === 'car'){
    response.ask('Which vehicle?', *activate utterance*);
  }
};
```

If this isnt possible, could I create a series of functions that handle each piece of information necessary and then change the target function for a single-word-intent each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do what your question is aimed at. What you're trying to avoid --not defining a Custom Slot Type-- is actually the answer to your problem.

You can use a `Custom Slot Type` for what you want. I agree that it would be ridiculous to list all the possible options, but that's the catch: you don't have to!

All you have to do is to define a Custom Slot Type, perhaps add a few values, because I'm not sure you can get away without and you're done. Alexa WILL SEND the value for the slot to your skill, even if it is not in the list. In Amazon words:

> Note that a custom slot type is not the equivalent of an enumeration. Values outside the list may still be returned if recognized by the spoken language understanding system. Although input to a custom slot type is weighted towards the values in the list, it is not constrained to just the items on the list. Your code still needs to include validation and error checking when using slot values. See the “Handling Possible Input Errors” section of Handling Requests Sent by Alexa.

You can find all about it [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference#h2_custom_syntax).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Ive added a list of about 300 car models and that seems to have done the trick.